# How do I find the IP address of a Dlink wireless router?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ip-address

How do I find out the IP address of a DLink Wireless router that I have plugged into my Wireless Router?  I want to reach the admin page and change some settings but I dunno how

Comment: You want to chain 2 wireless routers? If so, I'd recommend to connect one of them directly to your computer and set it up before connecting it to the other one.

Comment: Please add some information on what you're trying to do and add some info on your OS and the Router models

Comment: What PC os are you on, or are you on a mobile?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at your own network configuration when connected to the router:

If your IP is something like 192.168.1.X (where X is your IP) then the router will almost always be at 192.168.1.1 (this is the same if your IP is not like 192.168.1.X)

Just replace the X with a 1 in your browser's URL bar and that should take you to the router's admin panel

Answer (score 1):

The way the router is set up is that one of its ports is plugged into the main router, and it's set up to be on the same subnet as that one (ie., my main router gives out IPs at 192.168.1.100 +  and the wireless is 192.168.1.100)

The wireless router has its DHCP shut off.  It's also supposed to be "work as bridge" mode but I never found that setting.  At any rate, it works.

It's the procedure described in the manual under "setting up your wireless router to work as an access point" or similar

Comment: you seem to have posted this question from an unregistered account.  i'm merging the accounts now; you should regain ownership of the question automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried 192.168.1.1 ?

How exactly have you plugged a wireless router into a wireless router ? You've connected the two by cable or ... ? What does it say on the list of clients ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have plugged in a new, off the shelf router, it most likely will be configured to use static a static address and provide DHCP leases.

This will not be a good solution when behind another router as it is likely to conflict with your existing equipment - or alternatively, be on a slightly different subnet/network and have no active route.

When I am in a similar situation, I advise that you get any machine - and simply plug the router in to that, go to it's address - should be easy to find (Go to `Command Prompt`, type `ipconfig` and look up the default gateway) then set a new static IP that is on your current network and disable DHCP.

Then, you can plug it in to the router and simply go to the address you configured.

Answer (score 0):

On the subject of the generic "How do I get the IP of?", there is a fantastic little tool that I always keep handy on my flash drive "[Angry IP Scanner](http://www.angryip.org/w/Home)", never cared enough to find out where the name came from, but it has been an essential tool for me forever.

As an aside, almost every virus scanner will mark it as suspicious, so be aware that unless you mark it as allowed it might not be there next time you're looking for it.

Answer (score 0):

`tracert` command may be help. Its is tool like `ping` but do some more then it.  On command prompt write `tracert google.com` it will give you ip of your router....

Comment: I find the question unclear, but I believe that the OP has simply put the new router *on* the network, and has not yet configured it.  If it is not part of the path to the Internet, but is just sitting off to the side, then `tracert` won't find it.